# PL/SQL error in Aqua Data Studio

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to execute next code in Aqua Data Studio 8.0.22:

```
--  Add a new role for cashier.
declare 
    roleEntityID "Entity"."EntityID"%type;
begin
    select "EntityID_SEQ".NEXTVAL into roleEntityID from dual;
    insert into "Entity" ("EntityID") values(roleEntityID);
    insert into "Role" ("RoleID", "Name", "DisplayName") values (roleEntityID, 'Cashier', 'Cashier');
end;
```

But unfortunately I've got some errors, first of them is:

> > [Error] Script lines: 1-3 --------------------------  ORA-06550: line 3, column 41: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when
> >     expecting one of the following:
>
> := ( ; not null range default character  Script line 3, statement
>   line 3, column 41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how this is being run (as a script?), you may need to end the PLSQL block with a forward slash:

```
declare
--...
begin
--...
end;
/
```

And to show you that your code should work exactly as-is (on Oracle 11GR2; the script output from SQL Developer apparently doesn't show the semicolons after the `create`  or `select` statements or the slash on the line after the `end;` but all were present in the original buffer):

```
> create sequence "EntityID_SEQ"
sequence "EntityID_SEQ" created.
> create table "Entity"("EntityID" number)
table "Entity" created.
> create table "Role"("RoleID" number, "Name" varchar2(30), "DisplayName" varchar2(30))
table "Role" created.
> declare 
    roleEntityID "Entity"."EntityID"%type;
begin
    select "EntityID_SEQ".NEXTVAL into roleEntityID from dual;
    insert into "Entity" ("EntityID") values(roleEntityID);
    insert into "Role" ("RoleID", "Name", "DisplayName") values (roleEntityID, 'Cashier', 'Cashier');
end;
anonymous block completed
> select * from "Entity"
EntityID               
---------------------- 
1                      

 1 rows selected 

> select * from "Role"
RoleID                 Name                           DisplayName                    
---------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ 
1                      Cashier                        Cashier                        

 1 rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the quotes.  Not sure why you have them there at all

Comment: The double quotes force case-sensitivity for all the object names (tables, columns, sequence). If they were created with quotes, he needs to keep them. It wouldn't be an `ORA-06550` he'd get if they were the issue; it'd be a `ORA--00942: table or view does not exist` or `ORA-02289: sequence does not exist`